# Enterprise Security API for C++

Tags: c++, security, enterprise, owasp, esapi

We are currently working on an open source project for OWASP, creating a C++ API of enterprise security controls.

The Enterprise Security API (ESAPI) has already been defined for Java EE. We are well aware that requirements of security controls for the C++ language may vary to some degree. 
Undoubtedly, some of the largest security concerns stem from memory management, which we are not providing a solution for at this time. So far, we are focusing on several items taken from the ESAPI 2.0 for Java specification.  However, there are some questions we have specific to some of these security sections. Mainly, the Java ESAPI has a heavy slant towards web applications, which we know is not the norm for C++.  Therefore, we are looking for other areas where common security controls might help the C++ community. It would be useful to know what types of security issues commonly face C++ developers.

We are trying to identify how hackers attack and break your code so we can help provide the appropriate security controls to prevent it.

To aggregate feedback on this project we have created a Google survey; however, please feel free to leave your feedback here as well.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dE5feWtjYlBNU05lV1FxTGNLVExIMVE6MQ

---

**Proposed Security Controls** (taken from ESAPI 2.0 for Java):

- Authentication - Methods for generating and handling corroborating account credentials and session identifiers.
- User - Represents an application user or user account.
- Access Control - Methods that can be used in a wide variety of applications to enforce access control.
- Validation - Methods for canonicalizing and validating untrusted input.
- Encoding - Decoding input and encoding output so that it will be safe for a variety of interpreters.
- Execution - Used to run an OS command with reduced security risk.
- Encryption - Common encryption, cryptographic random numbers and strings, and hashing operations, and signatures. The cryptographic functionality will be built upon Wei Dai's Crypto++ library for C++. However, our intent is to provide crypto functionality that is simple enough for the average developer to use without any specific knowledge of cryptography apart from some basic terminology.
- Logging - Methods designed that can be used to log security events.

**Would you consider using this API?**

**Would this provide a benefit to your development / business?**

**Any Recommendations?**

Any additional information you can provide on this project is useful to us. If there are specific things that would be useful to include that are missing from the above list, or general recommendations you may have, that would be great. Are there things on the above list that you recommend that we leave out because there would be absolutely no way you would use it? If so, then also tell us about those things too.

---

Thank you for giving this your attention. We hope that creating an ESAPI for C++ will make it easier for developers to write more secure applications.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API
http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-cplusplus/

Comment: I really don't think it is possible to write security policies for a native language. If you do, you'll turn C++ in a managed language.